# Nested telerik RadGrid breaks validation

Tags: asp.net, webforms, telerik, radgrid

I have a nested Telerik RadGrid in my application. There are required field validators on most of the controls on the main page. The validation works perfectly if I submit the form without clicking the "Add New Item" button on the nested radgrid. However, when I add a new item to the nested radgrid, and leave certain required fields blank outside of the nested radgrid, I am able to submit the form despite the required field validators being place. Has anyone else experienced this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: i'm not sure exactly what you have, but try setting appropriate ValidationGroup settings for your templates. If none is set all input controls on the page are validated, which seems like your case.

Comment: What I ended up doing was manually rerunning client-side validation. Thank you for your advice. I will check into it.